# Jquery if its the first time element is being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, each, var

I need my script to do something on the first time an element is clicked and continue to do something different on click 2,3,4 and so on

```
$('selector').click(function() {  
//I would realy like this variable to be updated  
var click = 0;  
    if (click === 0) {  
        do this  
        var click = 1;  
    } else {  
        do this  
    }
});//end click
```

really I think it should rely on the variables but I can't think of how to update the variable from here on out any help would be awesome.

Comment: Someone should edit your post so that the code is indented properly and not all on one line.

Comment: I swear it is but im prob doing something wrong it says indent by 4 spaces????

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method. Consider your example:

```
$('selector').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        clickNum = $this.data('clickNum');

    if (!clickNum) clickNum = 1;

    alert(clickNum);

    $this.data('clickNum', ++clickNum);
});
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/uaaft/

Comment: Not quite "wrong" is it...but thanks for the heads up to the better link.

Comment: I did the exact same mistake in my post

Comment: yes this will definitley work and thank you for the link I tested it out great site that is to test code!!

Answer (score 9):

Use [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to persist your state with the element.

In your click handler,

use

> $(this).data('number_of_clicks')

to retrieve the value and

> $(this).data('number_of_clicks',some_value)

to set it.

Note: $(this).data('number_of_clicks') will return false if it hasn't been set yet

Edit: fixed link

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative might be to have two functions, and bind one using the [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function in `$(document).ready()` (or wherever you are binding your handlers), and in that function, bind the second function to be run for all subsequent clicks using `bind` or `click`.

e.g.

```
function FirstTime(element) {
   // do stuff the first time round here
   $(element.target).click(AllOtherTimes);
}

function AllOtherTimes(element) {
   // do stuff all subsequent times here
}

$(function() {
    $('selector').one('click', FirstTime);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is super easy in vanilla Js. This is using proper, different click handlers

```
const onNextTimes = function(e) {
    // Do this after all but first click
};

node.addEventListener("click", function onFirstTime(e) {
    node.addEventListener("click", onNextTimes);
}, {once : true});
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/addeventlistener-once), [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=once-event-listener)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need sequences of fixed behaviors, you can do this:

$('selector').toggle(function(){...}, function(){...}, function(){...},...);

Event handlers in the toggle method will be called orderly.

Comment: have you got reference to back that? .... oh yeah, it is in the docs.. http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/.. didn't know you could have more than two... funny that :)

Answer (score 0):

$('#foo').one('click', function() {
  alert('This will be displayed only once.');
});

this would bind click event to Corresponding Html element once and unbind it automatically after first event rendering.

Or alternatively u could  the following:

$("#foo").bind('click',function(){

// Some activity

$("#foo").unbind("click");
// bind it to some other event handler.

});