# Pure JS "If stament depending the number of click"

Tags: javascript, button, if-statement

I was searching for this problem but I didn't find a solution. I'm trying to create a code where when you click a button do one thing, and when you press the same button later do other thing. I tried to create and "if-else" statement but I can't (don't know) how to count the number of clicks.

The code is:

```
<button type="submit" id="btnshwmap" onClick="init()" >Show Map</button>
```

And the if-else :

```
function init() {
    var click =0;
    if (click === 0) {  
        do this  
        var click = 1;  
    } else {  
        do this  
    }
});//end click
```

Basically I'm trying to use this example [Jquery if its the first time element is being clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688205/jquery-if-its-the-first-time-element-is-being-clicked)

But the answer are using Jquery I'm trying not use any library.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `click` will be reseted to `0` everytime you call `init`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to have the click counter outside the function, in the global area.

```
var click =0;

function init() {

    if (click == 0) {  
        //do this once
        click = 1;  
    } else {  
        //do this every other time
    }
});//end click
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.
Thank all for all the replies!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you keep on resetting `click=0` every time you call the function.

I would suggest something like this:

```
function init() {
    if( !init.click) {
        // first, third, fifth etc.
        init.click = 1;
    ]
    else {
        // second, fourth...
        init.click = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try toggling the value set for the button with the click. Something like:

```
function init() {
    var value = document.getElementById('btnshwmap').value;
    if (value === 1) {  
        do this  
        document.getElementById('btnshwmap').value = 2;  
    } else {  
        do this  
        document.getElementById('btnshwmap').value = 1;
    }
});//end click
```

Or keep a global variable to track the click status, rather than setting it every time you run the function.